# How to get all Azure Resources without tags in a Azure Resource Group using REST Apis

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

How to get all Azure Resources without tags in a Azure Resource Group using REST APIs
please help for this question. how to find Rest Apis and please suggest documentations also.

Thank you

i am try to search documentaton, but not found this api.

Answer (score 1):

Here are links to Azure Resource Graph Rest API querying:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-rest-api
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureresourcegraph/resourcegraph(2021-03-01)/resources/resources?tabs=HTTP

Follow PowerShell steps to obtain your Bearer token which is used to authenticate the call to the REST API URI. This can be done in PowerShell or POSTMAN. I would recommend POSTMAN.